# Getting a file without an extensions mime-type

Tags: ios, titanium, mime-types

I'm downloading a jpg into the applicationDataDirectory with the Titanium HTTP Client.

Im saving the filename as a md5 hash of the URL to be able to do simple caching via the URL.

However if I save the file without an extension eg. just as sf98isdi8j3k34k3kj34k no .jpg when I run

```
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile( filePath );
var mimeType = file.blob.getMimeType();
```

it returns `"application/octet-stream"`

This is because `Mimetypes.m` contains the following code

```
+ (NSString *)mimeTypeForExtension:(NSString *)ext 
{ 
    [Mimetypes initialize]; 
    NSString *result=[mimeTypeFromExtensionDict objectForKey:[[ext pathExtension] lowercaseString]]; 
    if (result == nil){ 
        result = @"application/octet-stream"; 
    } 
    return result; 
}
```

It soley relies on the extension, so you could change the file extension and cause issues.

How would I go about checking the mime-type based off the raw data of the file, rather than file extensions in titanium- specifically iOS

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Ti.Filesystem.File has no MimeType property, maybe you are thinking of a [Ti.Blob](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Blob)?

I have used this code with success for fetching the mimeType of some data, similar to what you already have!

```
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile( filePath );
var blob = file.read();
var mimeType = blob.getMimeType();
```

Looking at [TiBlob.m](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/iphone/Classes/TiBlob.m) and [Mimetypes.m](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/iphone/Classes/Mimetypes.m) this may not solve the problem, but I seem to recall having success with this.

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo. Your solution doesnt work in the case where a file doesnt have an extension. as the Mimetype class uses the extension to give you the mime type, rather than reading the actual file.